I sent money to the correct account number but wrong Swift code
I have sent a payment for beneficiary that uses Citi bank but used the swift code of another subsidiary of another citi bank account, the account number is still correct and the beneficiary said that he didn’t receive the money, what will happen now?

This looks like a duplicate of Sent wrong payment to right IBAN but wrong SWIFT. What will happen now?.

Have you tried calling the bank?

This question is similar to: Sent wrong payment to right IBAN but wrong SWIFT. What will happen now?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
